# Add html to chrome current tab

Tags: google-chrome, content-script

I want to add html to chrome in current tab. 
For Example:
following code add to source html code of chrome current tab

```
<div id="myDiv"> <span> My Text </span> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
<html><div id="myDiv"> <span> My Text </span> </div></html>
```

Comment: How do I add this html code to chrome current tab source code?